# Change firebase region when deployed

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

My app always gets redirected to `us-central1` region after deployment even though it's already been set to `asia-northeast1` in my console

[image]

And I even set the region in code manually

[image]

But after `firebase deploy` and try to go and visit the site, it redirects me back to `us-central1`

[image]

Comment: Contact Firebase support directly if deployment doesn't work the way you expect, and explain the problem. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Yeah, I've already sent them a ticket and still waiting for a reply. I'm just wondering if someone here also got the same problem as me who also knows a fix.

Comment: i know we're sat in 2022, but ive just hit this issue, did you ever find a resolution?